# How to use reject with a counter in Ruby or Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use `reject` method in ruby but I need to stop after a certain count. For example

```
users = Users.all # this will be list of 1000 users

count = 0
user.reject! do |user|
 user.name == 'python'
end
```

I want to stop the reject condition when count reaches 100, so something like

```
count = 0
user.reject! do |user|
  user.name == 'python'
  count += 1
  if count == 100
    break
  end 
end
```

I agree the syntax above is wrong, and need some help from you. I am fairly new to ruby so I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: `user.name = 'python'` this is assigning the word `python` to the user name... is that what you want? or do you actually want `'python' == user.name` (ie reject if the user name is python). Note that if you put it the way around that I did... it's more likely to let you know when there's an error in your `=`/`==` because you can't assign a value to a string (at least not this way)

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 3):

The `reject` method takes a block that evaluates to `true` or `false`, and it will reject all elements that evaluates to `true`.

So, having all the other code inside the block will cause `reject` to malfunction.

I think the way to do it is to split the `users` array into two: the first 100 and last 900.

```
first_users = users[0...100]
last_users = users[100...1000]
```

Now, you can use the `reject` method on `first_users` and then combine the arrays.

```
first_users.reject! do |user|
  user.name == 'python'
end
```

Notice the `==` instead of `=`. You need a boolean expression inside the block.

Finally, you just add the arrays together

```
users = first_users + last_users
```

**EDIT**

You can run a counter from 99 to 0, which will loop through each of the first 100 elements, and you delete any one that matches the condition.

```
99.downto(0).each do |i|
  users.delete_at(i) if users[i].name == 'python'
end
```

Comment: You can also use [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-first) and [`last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-last), like `first(100)` and `last(900)`. Plus you can chain this, like `first(100).reject! ...`

Comment: count variable should get triggered every time you reject an object and break out if the count value reached a certain number, in my case is 100. I don't have to divide database into blocks.

Comment: what i'm trying to say that the `reject` method does not work like that. Yes, the `count` variable does count up, and the loop breaks when it is 100, but I noticed that nothing is rejected, and you end up with the original list.

Comment: maybe you can run a `while` loop with an index counter to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there any other way I can reject with counter? I shouldn't be using any other thing

Comment: Then I have to use delete with while, which is really expensive operation.

Comment: see my edit. You can run a counter with `delete_at` method

Comment: the problem with your edit is that you are looping over the first 100 values and trying to reject the ones matching the condition. I am looking to loop over all the values and reject the first 100 matching values. I hope you understood the difference.

Comment: I understood your question as rejecting any user with the name Python in the first 100 users. Can you update your question with examples to show exactly what you need

Answer (score 2):

It's also likely `User.all`, but remember, calling `all` is **hazardous** as it could load in so much data your server crashes.

What you want is probably:

```
User.where.not(name: 'python').order(:id).limit(100)
```

This will select the first 100 people that do not have the name `python` in order of ID. Try and do as much filtering in the database as possible before hitting the Ruby layer.

The error in your code is you've done an assignment. To rewrite this so it works:

```
User.all.reject do |user|
  user.name == 'python'
end.first(100)
```

Though as I've mentioned this is very inefficient, it will use tons of memory for no reason, and might actually crash your server for non-trivial numbers of users.

**Edit**: If you want to mask out the first 100 people named `'python'` then here you go:

```
User.all.reject do |user|
  case (user.name)
  when 'python'
    excluded += 1
    excluded < 100
  else
    true
  end
end
```

It's a rather odd thing to need to do. You can probably just delete these from the database if you don't want them:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE name='python' LIMIT 100
```

Comment: hey do you need `User.all.reject!` to make sure the User object is affected

Comment: `reject!` is an in-place modifier and might return `nil` if no records were altered. You can't chain that method.

Comment: the `count` is separate from `database count` which you're trying to do here. I can't use the database first or last method

Comment: count variable should get triggered every time you reject an object and break out if the count value reached a certain number, in my case is 100.

Comment: What's your goal here? I'm not even sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to delete the first 100 users from an array where `user.name == python` and the `users` object is created using `User.all` table. Just the first 100 and there are many users in the array.